# How do you make a count that counts the number of page-views? (PHP)

Tags: php, counter

For each ad on my site, I would like a box that shows the number of views it has (similar to this site).

How would I capture the number of page views an ad has? Is there a function that does this in PHP?

Comment: Deleted my answer since the answers already posted posed a better alternative approach that mine.

Answer (score 4):

Well, no there is no function that does this magically : you'll have to do a bit of work -- not that hard, though ;-)

There are two possible things you can count.

For the first one, **number of times an ad is displayed**, the basic idea is :

- Your are displaying an add -- you already know how to do that
- When displaying it, you'll update a counter, probably in your database :

  - Your SQL query will look like `update ad_counters set counter = counter + 1 where ad_id = 123`
  - `123` being replaced by the identifier of your ad, of course
- And, when displaying the ad, you'll have to select that counter, and display it alongside the ad.

For the second one, **number of times an ad is clicked**, the basic idea is generally :

- Not have the ad be a direct link to the page of the product
- Instead, the link of the ad will look like `http://yoursite.com/ad.php?id=123`
- And, when someone load that page, it will :

  - increment the counter of clicks : `update ad_clicks_counter set counter = counter + 1 where ad_id = 123`
  - redirect the user to the real page of the ad, or display it directly.

In fact, this is precisely what's done on SO :

- An ad has a link such as `http://ads.stackoverflow.com/a.aspx?Task=Click&ZoneID=4&CampaignID=785&AdvertiserID=161&BannerID=1123&SiteID=1&RandomNumber=384213225&Keywords=php%2ccounter%2cx-user-highrep%2cx-user-registered`
- And when you click on it, you are redirected to the real page of the ad, which can be such as `http://www.xpolog.com/home/solutions/landing.jsp`

Of course, those two counters can be in the same table -- or even in the table in which you have the list of all ads :-)

Comment: thank you!! time to get to work :)
I think I'll just add a counter field to my table and the "UPDATE SQL" on top of the ad.php script.